# Subcollection not created in Firestore due to rules in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on a **Flutter** project with a **"Bookmark"** feature implemented in which Users can create a Bookmark of their own and then save their Product in their Bookmark, **kinda like Instagram**.

The feature has been successfully implemented. It was all working well earlier until I decided to make my Firestore secure. Now I get "Permission Denied" when I try to create a new Bookmark in the collection having hierarchy like this: `Users/{uid}/Bookmarks/{b_id}/`. Here instead let's create a bookmark called "Dr.Dtanis Visit" with its hierarchy being like: `Users/{uid}/Bookmarks/{b_id}/Dr.Dtanis/{custom_bookmark_id}`, I will get a "Permission Denied" Error, instead of operation being successful.

The issue is mostly related to my rules. Is there any way around this? Or do I need to change anything?

**This is a demo of my current Firebase rule:**

```
match /Users/{userId} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  match /Bookmarks/{bookmarkName} {
    allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, create, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

**Do Note:**  I can read and write data in any existing bookmark as well as I am able to delete them but cannot create a new Bookmark(Collection) whenever I want to.

**Here is my Flutter code which is used to handle the task of creating a new Bookmark**

```dart
void _submit() async {
    setState(() => _submitted = true);
    if (_errorText == null) {
      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
      final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Bookmarks").get();
      bool nodup = false;

      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (final documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          final collectionName = documentSnapshot.data()['collectionName'];

          if (collectionName == _controller.text.toString()) {
            setState(() {
              nodup = false;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              nodup = true;
            });
          }
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          nodup = true;
        });
      }
    }
 
    // Important Part
    if (nodup) {
        final bookmarkRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('Bookmarks')
            .add({'collectionName': _controller.text.toString()});

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('Bookmarks')
            .doc(bookmarkRef.id)
            .collection(_controller.text.toString())
            .add({
          'key': widget.keyo,
          'productName': widget.name,
          'color': widget.color.toString()
        });

        if (mounted) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Product added to the Collection",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff1f7f3),
            textColor: AppTheme.signAppColor,
            fontSize: 14,
          );
        }
      }

    if (mounted) Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

**The error I am getting while executing the code:**

````
W/Firestore( 8657): (24.4.3) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(Bookmarks order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

E/flutter ( 8657): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.```
````

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.